# Fast DOM animation with JS

Tags: javascript

I'm currently designing a website and I have one section that contains 3 dropdowns.

On the div click, the contentof the dropdown is meant to show, and the icon associated to it is meant to collapse. It goes on the other side aswell if the dropdown is to be closed.

I was using querySelector before and switched to getElementById after reading and seeing on JSPerf that the latter was better in terms of performance.

```
  if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('show-info-1')).display === "none") {
    document.getElementById('show-info-1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('show-open-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('show-close-1').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('show-info-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('show-open-1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('show-close-1').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
document.getElementById("show-2").onclick = function() {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('show-info-2')).display === "none") {
    document.getElementById('show-info-2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('show-open-2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('show-close-2').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('show-info-2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('show-open-2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('show-close-2').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
document.getElementById("show-3").onclick = function() {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('show-info-3')).display === "none") {
    document.getElementById('show-info-3').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('show-open-3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('show-close-3').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('show-info-3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('show-open-3').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('show-close-3').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

I'd really like the DOM animation to be slightly faster because it really looks slow from here. I'd like to avoid using jQuery aswell, as I know it's a solution but VanillaJS is enough for that I guess.

Comment: If a simple `.style.display = 'block'` is _"slow"_ then there are other problems than if `.querySelector` or `.getElementById` is "faster"

Comment: it cannot be slow, it should  takes a few ms. Have you timed the function?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar How could I time it?

Comment: put a `console.time("foo")` at the beginning and a `console.timeEnd("foo")` at the end

Comment: Alright, timed it and it's performing actions under 0.06 ms, which I guess proves that my impression of it being slow is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered separating your concerns and leaning more heavily on your CSS to do the work?

Something like:

HTML:

```html
<div id="btn-wrapper-2">
  <!-- "show-info-2" -->
  <!-- "show-open-2" -->
  <!-- "show-close-2" -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.enable-btns-2 > .dropdown {
  display = "block";
}

.enable-btns-2 > .icon {
  display = "none";
}

...
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("show-2").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("btn-wrapper-2").classList.toggle("enable-btns-2");
}
```

Comment: Side note, I kept `getElementById` to respect your OP, but if you're having speed issues, it's probably not related to `querySelector` and is due to some other logic in your codebase.